# Compiler Error: Invalid Outside Procedure for Excel custom VBA function

Tags: excel, vba

I am following this guide to convert Hexadecimal Color to GBD, https://exceloffthegrid.com/convert-color-codes/.

Here is an example of my input, when I hit enter I get the error, "Compiler Error: Invalid Outside Procedure".

[example input.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znnXT.png)

Why do I get an error for this code?

Code:

```
    Function GetRGBFromHex(hexColor As String, RGB As String) As String

hexColor = VBA.Replace(hexColor, "#", "")
hexColor = VBA.Right$("000000" & hexColor, 6)

Select Case RGB

    Case "B"
        GetRGBFromHex = VBA.Val("&H" & VBA.Mid(hexColor, 5, 2))

    Case "G"
        GetRGBFromHex = VBA.Val("&H" & VBA.Mid(hexColor, 3, 2))

    Case "R"
        GetRGBFromHex = VBA.Val("&H" & VBA.Mid(hexColor, 1, 2))

End Select

End Function
```

Comment: Check there are no text lines  before the Function line, like comments without `'`.

Comment: Yes, the code works for me so nothing wrong with it

Comment: Fixed it, I had to resave the file as a "Macro enabled excel file"